# Extension Methods in Java possible without breaking Binary Backwards Compatibility?

Tags: java, extension-methods, backwards-compatibility

Several languages have externsion methods like C#, Ruby, Smalltalk, Kotlin, Scala. The idea is that you can add methods to a class that is closed for extension like system classes such as String, Integer or final classes such as ArrayList.

So instead of having all those Util-Classes you just add the respective extension method. So instead of StringUtils.split(...) you would call "foo".split().

Java does not have extension methods. My question is whether extension methods could be added to Java without breaking binary backwards compatibility as for exanple with Java8 lambdas or other features in the past. The question is only about whether it can be done without braking backwards compatibility or not.

In C# and Kotlin extension methods are implemented as static methods. So, in the same way for Java there would be some additional syntax for StringUtils.split(...), which would tell the Java compiler that "foo".split() at compile time has to be replaced with StringUtils.split(...). At least, I think this is what happens in C# and Kotlin.

Again, my question is only about whether extension methods in Java can be done without braking backwards compatibility or not. Just that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the ultimate answer to this but here's how Kotlin does it, which would probably be possible for Java as well.

Let's consider a simple extension on `String`:

```
fun String.lengthSquare() = length * length
```

The Kotlin compiler generates bytecode similar to the following (shown as corresponding Java code):

```
public static final int lengthSquare(@NotNull String $this$lengthSquare) {
   Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull($this$lengthSquare, "$this$lengthSquare");
   return $this$lengthSquare.length() * $this$lengthSquare.length();
}
```

So basically it just creates a static method that takes in a `String`, just as we know it from utility methods. I believe the Java compiler could do something similar. All call sites of those extension functions, of course, will use that static method in the JVM byte code.

*More Information on Kotlin Extensions*

> Extensions do not actually modify classes they extend. By defining an extension, you do not insert new members into a class, but merely make new functions callable with the dot-notation on variables of this type.

- Read here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply, s1m0nw1. I'm quite sure that with static methods being used to mimic extension methods the changes are only in the compiler and does not reach the byte code level. But I'm not completely sure. The example in Kotlin is nice, but Kotlin is a new language that had extension methods from the beginning. So this is no indicator that extension methods in Java would not break backwards compatibility.